# Fatal Error The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted (already tried solution in other thread)

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I get the pgadmin 4 server could not be contacted. This is the first time I installed on my computer. I tried the run as admin solution, remove the app/roaming files, restart the posgresql services, tried to modify the config.py, config_distro.py. All of it did not help. Please help thank you.

Here is the error

### pgAdmin Runtime Environment

Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment:

- ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
- APPDATA: C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Roaming
- CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_2976_GCSFUFUNDXSUIDKX
- CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
- CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
- CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
- CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
- COMPUTERNAME: CHENONN
- ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
- DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
- HOMEDRIVE: C:
- HOMEPATH: \Users\lco73
- JAVA_HOME: C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\
- LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Local
- LOGONSERVER: \CHEO
- M2_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3
- MAVEN_HOME: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3
- NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 16
- OneDrive: C:\Users\lco73\OneDrive
- OneDriveConsumer: C:\Users\lco73\OneDrive
- OS: Windows_NT
- Path: C:\Users\lco73\introcs\java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v96\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin;C:\Program Files\TMC-cli;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\lco73\anaconda3;C:\Users\lco73\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\lco73\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\lco73\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\lco73\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Local\Programs\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10.9-hotspot\bin;C:\Users\lco73\introcs\j3d\bin;C:\Users\lco73\introcs\bin;C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin
- PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
- pgAdmin: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\bin
- PGADMIN_INT_KEY: de63dec9-3578-472a-af02-2786fce52e26
- PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 63995
- PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
- postgreSQL: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
- PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
- PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 165 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
- PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
- PROCESSOR_REVISION: a505
- ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
- ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
- ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
- ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
- PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
- PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
- PyCharm Community Edition: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin;
- PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\lco73\Desktop\Python\Convolutional_neural_network-master
- SystemDrive: C:
- SystemRoot: C:\Windows
- TEMP: C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Local\Temp
- TMP: C:\Users\lco73\AppData\Local\Temp
- USERDOMAIN: CHENONN
- USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: CHENONN
- USERNAME: lco73
- USERPROFILE: C:\Users\lco73
- windir: C:\Windows
- ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN: 1

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in 
app = create_app()
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_*init*_.py", line 347, in create_app
if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, if you are first time using PostgreSQL and new to SQL stuff, probably there is some python module not installed. Go to the folder C:(YourUserFolder)\PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web and run setup.py using terminal. It will list down the module missing when you run. Install the modules and run again to see which other module is missing. Or you can use an IDE that can check which module that is not install in the _ *init* _.py files in the "PostgreSQL\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin" folder.

Answer (score 8):

I've been struggling with this problem for quite sometime.

Here's the steps you have to follow for Windows:

> 1. Go To Add or Remove programs, you can find this in search

> 2. Search for postgreSQL

> 3. Click on uninstall and when promoted click something like "individual components"

> 4. Click on PgAdmin4 and uninstall it.

> 5. Once step 4 is done then run pgAdmin as administrator. **MAKE SURE TO RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR** that's the only time it worked for me

Comment: This did it for me 2023

Comment: Link to installer: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\ and then install pgAdmin 4

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it started working in `Windows 10`.

Go to `Control Panel` -> `Programs & Features` -> Right click `PostgreSQL 15` (whichever version you have installed) -> `Uninstall / Change` -> `Individual Components` -> select `pgAdmin` -> Click next and wait for uninstall to complete.

Now download `pgAdmin` latest version and install and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

**Another aspect:**

1. Just go to *environment variables* in windows cPanel.
2. Open **Path** variable
3. Check if there any *C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL* values
4. Remove them, and restart **pgAdmin**.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted" when re-installing PostgreSql on a Windows 7 machine that I need to keep using for certain reasons.

Obviously Windows 7 is not supported anymore in newer PostgreSQL 10-versions. Seems to be an issue with a missing flask-Module of the Python framework that is delivered with pgAdmin, perhaps the reason behind is the VPN I'm working in doesn't allow to download modules. Didn't get deeper into it.

First tried to run version 10.20-2 x64. Later it turned out that older version 10.12-2 x64 is working on Windows 7.
Searched on the net for a download of older postgresql-10.12-2-windows-x64.exe, found it here https://soft.uclv.edu.cu/Postgres/

Also see
https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-windows/

"pgAdmin is available for 64 bit Windows™ 7 SP1 (desktop) or 2008R2 (server) and above, up to v4.30."

Answer (score 0):

Solution:: "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:" error served to you if you are using Postgre SQL for the first time.   Some Python libraries are missing from your system.  Try to install those libraries first in the "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web" root folder using the window or any other terminal. And then restart the Postgre\PgAdmin4.   The fatal error will be resolved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got a same error. After reinstalling the whole thing and trying the other solutions I basically on did the following:

1. Installing Python
2. Cleaning the %temp% file.

Answer (score 0):

On me, It seems the problem was that pgAdmin could not select a free port randomly and I put it a fixed one, not used in "netstat -a" list, and pgAdmin has started.

Answer (score 0):

Restart my computer worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar message,when starting it first time.
I did not started pgAdmin4 as an administrator.
Starting it this way solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Select configure, uncheck Fixed Port, and then restart the program. It worked for me by doing it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Is correct for my try everythin mentione here and work it, becouse I try one per one and no work it so I when to do everthin mentionate here
, I was unistalla PGADMIN Uninstall / Change -> Individual Components , after delete this director  C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\ , and then delete all file of pgadmin on the previos installation. and then donwload pgamdin recent version. finally works it